# Can't install MySQL on the XAMPP control panel

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I can't start MySQL on the XAMPP control panel. Here is the error I am receiving:

```
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:40:19 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: MySQL must be Installed otherwise it could not give you error messages. It looks like you already have a MySQL instance installed and it is auto started and already using port 3306 (the default) Look see if you have another MySQL or mariaDB. If you do, backup any databases that yo created in there and then uninstall it

Comment: Did you `Press the Logs button to view error logs and check` and read around ?

Comment: Did you `check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues` ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I deleted previous files and it now has a green highlight in the XAMPP control panel. Does this mean it is completed?

Comment: put `services` into the windows search box, in the window that launches do you see a `MYSQL` or `mariaDB` that is STARTED?

Comment: Also enter `Event Viewer` into the windows search box. Click `Windows Logs` in the left pane. and then `Application` In the list of events do you see any messages from `MYSQL` or `mariaDB`

Comment: Deleting previous files is not the best way to UNINSTALL something, but if its working, just remember that you did not uninstall properly in case it all goes pear shaped later

Comment: I uninstalled I didn't delete any files. Thanks for the help I have it working now

Answer (score 0):

in the xampp control panel search for the mysql config file "my.ini" and open it: [image of control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAKME.png)

then look for the port by default "3306" and change it to "3307" and save the file, there are two places where the port in configured.